# How to determine whether it is safe to delete a custom object?

Tags: custom-object, deprecation

We have a number of custom objects in our org that look like they can be deprecated. Before I do so, I'd like to be sure it's not going to break anything e.g. connected apps etc. Is there a way to discover what (if anything) might still be dependent on these custom objects?

Comment: I'm fairly sure, but could be wrong. Salesforce won't allow objects to be deleted if they're connected in some way to other objects (e.g. LookUp or Master Detail).

Answer (score 2):

Ideally salesforce does not allow you to delete objects that have dependencies existing in your org, it does not matter if the object is deprecated functionally or not. Salesforce checks if the custom object you are about to delete is referenced anywhere in code, if it is then it cannot be deleted.

The easiest way to check if your custom object is referenced anywhere in code, is to edit the object and try to change its API Name. If the system allows you to do so, it means that the object is not referenced anywhere in the code. If there are references in the code, the system keeps on listing these references until you remove them all - and only then you can have a successful change in the API name.

If the api name could be successfully changed, hence no code references for the object. Then the second part that comes into play, that prevents object deletion is the presence of relationship fields(lookup or Master Detail) in other objects that links to the object we want to delete. We have to completely remove those fields from the database(delete + erase) for us to be able to delete the custom object. Another point to be noted is that, when you try to delete the master detail or lookup fields, pointing to our object from the related objects, we may have to delete other components first - formulas,validation rules, workflows etc that depend on the lookup field.

Summarising, To delete a custom object:

1. Code references to the custom object need to be removed - find there out by attempting to change the object API Name.
2. Relationship fields(lookup or MD) pointing to the object in the related objects also need to be removed(deleted and erased). Might have to delete those components in other objects depending on these MD/lookup fields first - try deleting the object to get these ones.

Hope this helps.
Thanks @Adrian Larson for pointing out improvements.

Cheers

Comment: What about references from config aspects such as formulas?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes Sir, you are right I believe. Those too should prevent the object from being deleted. I believe that they would show up as references that need to be taken are of before deleting the object, when one attempts to delete the object. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: It's not mentioned in your answer and I also seem to recall it not being a blocker in my experience, but perhaps I am mis-remembering. It would be nice to get confirmation. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson On it already :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson The mere presence of a relationship field, connecting the object we want to delete, in another object is enough for salesforce to prevent us from deleting the object. To finally delete the object - we need to delete + erase the field(lookup or MD to our object to delete) from the related object. Will update the answer appropriately. You got keen eyes :)